# Dual monitors reset to mirrored after sleeping

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend

Anytime the system sleeps and often when it is locked the duel monitor setup which extends is reverted back to mirrored.

$ uname -a

```
Linux bill-deskop 5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

$ lsb_release -a

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

NOTE: This is with it configured how I want.
$ xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: Still going into Display every time my system sleeps to change Mirrored back to extended. :( No one else seems to have this problem?

Comment: So, I decided to switch the cables for the monitor so that the left-right primary-secondary was naturally the default rather than switching monitors position using the "Display" app. Now, after having made that change, when it comes back from sleep or being locked it is NOT in mirrored display mode like it had been previously. However, every time it restores the display from that mode all of the windows are now displayed in the primary monitor. Except....sometime one non-full screened window will not be moved and will show in its original position in the secondary monitor.